# Push/Pop vs Mov in MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

A simple question but I do not know the answer.

What is the reason for:

```
push wParam
pop char
```

where `wParam` is defined as type WPARAM and `char` is defined as type WPARAM.

Why can't I simply

```
mov char, wParam
```

I have a feeling it has to do with addresses, but I can't justify it. MASM spits out a non-descript error when I try to use the `mov` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because both are memory addresses and in x86 assembly there is no such instruction as `mov mem,mem` (`mov char,wParam` in this case).

Therefore, to do that, you need to use either `push` & `pop`, or first move the value into some register with `mov reg,mem` and from that register to memory with `mov mem,reg`.

Comment: I haven't seen the `push`/`pop` method in any disassemblies of compiled C programs - is here a reason one would use that instead of `mov`ing through a register?

Comment: @us2012 x86 doesn't have that many registers, sometimes it may be the easiest option, if the alternative would be needing to `push reg` `mov reg,mem` `mov mem,reg` `pop reg`. I like to keep things simple, to the extent it's possible.

Comment: The push,pop pattern is also used in registers. `push 7` then `pop ecx`. Why not `mov ecx, 7`